# How to add points to two plots parallelly ? (in R)

Tags: r, layout, plot, scatter-plot, par

I am looking for ways to add points to three different plots in parallel.

I have three scatter plots named `s3d1`, `s3d2` and `s3d3` in a single window

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,1,3),2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
s3d1<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
s3d2<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
s3d3<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
```

If I try to add points to `s3d1`,

```
s3d1$points3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],col="red")
```

The points would go to `s3d3` but not `s3d1`. What am I missing ?

More info : I obtain data points while running a program. So, I need to add points to each of these plots as-and-when I get the data specific to that particular plot.

**Update :**

Tried `par()` function as well

```
par(fig=c(0,0.65,0,1), new=TRUE)
s3d1<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
par(fig=c(0.7,1,0.5,1), new=TRUE)
s3d2<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
par(fig=c(0,0.65,0,1), new=TRUE)
s3d1$points3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],col="red")
```

`s3d1$points3d` doesn't add new points to `s3d1` (and not even to `s3d2`). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of `points3d()` by just trying to execute `s3d1$points3d`, you'll see that it just adds points to an existing plot that is assumed to be already open. In other words, the points/plot are not stored in the s3d1,2,3 objects, but simply the transformation info needed to plot to the different views.

Soo, to do what you're trying to do, you'll just have to use the normal graphics device commands. For instance, `dev.new` will open a new plot window, and `dev.set` can switch between the active ones. You could do something like:

```
dev.new(); h1=dev.cur()
s3d1<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
dev.new(); h2=dev.cur()
s3d2<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
dev.new(); h3=dev.cur()
s3d3<-scatterplot3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],main="common",pch=20)
dev.set(h1)
s3d1$points3d(mtcars[,3],mtcars[,4],mtcars[,5],col="red")
```

Also check out `?dev.new` for more info.

Comment: Sorry, I must have informed it earlier : Actually, I am plotting all three in a single window using layout( ). So, using dev.new( ) opens a new window which is not desirable

Comment: Ohhhh...thanks for the clarification! The `points3d` call is using whichever cell was plotted to last, which is the bottom right one. I think the best solution is to just plot from scratch each cycle. Good luck!

Comment: @user1029725 Yes, I have found `layout` most useful when I just need to quickly throw up some plots. For more custom subplots I've always used `par(mfrow)`, etc..